# A book about a primitive guy whose home was threatened by monsters so he went to find other monsters to defeat them

Tags: story-identification, books

Around 15 years ago I read a book about a guy (he was a primitive barbarian hero type if I recall correctly, you know loincloth, muscular, the whole trope), whose home was being attacked by some monsters (I can't remember the type of the monster though). In response to that he embarked on a quest to find some other monsters that can guard him from the ones attacking.

There was many different species/cultures he encountered on his journey, and I think it's implied high tech existed, but was not available to our hero and his people.

I also think I remember the hero having a wife, which died.

The cover of the book (Polish edition) had some type of dinosaur or other big creature on the cover.

One additional info I remembered was that he was traveling with a guy who seemed to be more advanced than him (in terms of tech and knowledge, generally speaking).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So after another week of searching, I finally found the book:

It's "[Łowy na węże morskie](http://lubimyczytac.pl/ksiazka/100195/lowy-na-weze-morskie)" (English title "[Serpent​ Catch](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1251430.Serpent_Catch)" I believe) by  Dave Wolverton.

Answer (score 3):

Aside from the "monsters" attacking the protagonist's home directly, this rather sounds like the plot of *Cluster* and following, published in 1977 by Piers Anthony -- Flint of Outland is so named because he makes flint tools, and he's really good at it.  He's chosen (because of his incredibly high "Kirlian" score,  the strength of his personal aura) to represent humanity in a quest to pass the technology of "transfer" to other "spheres" near the one of humanity.

He visits several other cultures with some of the most *alien* aliens I've ever encountered, becomes a hero, passes the technology -- and eventually dies.

Comment: I checked it out and this doesn't look like what I'm looking for - but you added a "must read" to my list, thanks!